# Decimal places are not coming in Formula field(number) in html email template

Tags: email, formula, currency

I have a currency formula field field1__c which is again referenced in another formula field Field2__c(number).
I have selected decimal place as 2.When I use this formula field in Field2__c decimal places are not coming.
I used the below formula for Field2__c.

```
text(floor(Field1__c)) &"."& lpad(text((Field1__c-floor(Field2__c))*100),2,"0")
```

Now I am getting the decimal places.But I want the currency format in the email which is not coming.

Comment: Here's how to debug complex formula fields - create test formula fields that you put on the page layout for each expression; for example, a formula field `f1 = text(floor(Field1__c)`; `f2 = (Field1__c-floor(Field2__c))`; etc. and then you can see where things go awry

Comment: What do you mean by "currency format"? The currency symbol? Something like this would be a good start: `{!CASE(relatedTo.CurrencyIsoCode, 
'CHF', 'S₣',
'CZK', 'Kč',
'DKK', 'kr',
'EUR', '€',
'GBP', '£',
'HUF', 'Ft',
'NOK', 'kr',
'SEK', 'kr',
'USD', '$',   
relatedTo.CurrencyIsoCode)}`

Comment: Format should be like 10,000,000.00.I dont want the currency symbol.